# How to Left Join a Dataframe into an Existing Table in Databricks

Tags: python, sql, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, databricks

I have a delta table in Databricks that I am loading into a dataframe to perform a specific numpy operation:

```
import pyspark.pandas as ps
df = spark.sql("SELECT Id,Field_to_Transform FROM bronze.Table_A where Field_to_Transform is not null").toPandas()
```

The operation I perform is to remove special characters:

```
df['Transformed_Field'] = [''.join(e for e in x if e.isalnum()) for x in df['Field_to_Transform ']]
df.drop(['Field_to_Transform '], axis=1)
```

So this leaves me with the dataframe "df" which has just the `id` and the `Transformed_Field` in it:

| Id | Transformed_Field |
| --- | --- |
| 00A1 | 12345 |
| 00A2 | 123456 |
| 00A3 | 1234 |
| 00A4 | 1234568 |

Now I want to left join the df back to `bronze.Table_A` in databricks by simply joining back on the `id` field.

What is the most effecient way to join `df` back to `bronze.Table_A`?
Things I have tried so far:

- Saved the entire `bronze.Table_A` in a new dataframe `df2`, used df.merge to put them together, and then created a brand new table. This worked but it was way too excessive and I do not need a new table, just the transformed column joined back.
- Tried to use spark.sql to perform the left join in a SQL query but it seems I cannot access a `df` inside a spark.sql query.

Any help is much appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Option 1 - DataFrame API way

The first option is a modification of your first bullet point:

> Saved the entire bronze.Table_A in a new dataframe df2, used df.merge to put them together, and then created a brand new table. This worked but it was way too excessive and I do not need a new table, just the transformed column joined back.

The `merge` operation is a Pandas method and not PySpark, hence the performance might not be optimal - docs [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.pandas/api/pyspark.pandas.DataFrame.merge.html?highlight=merge#pyspark-pandas-dataframe-merge). Loading the whole table into DataFrame is the correct approach, that just needs the built-in `join` method to the required *left-join*, like this:

```py
table_df = spark.read.table("bronze.Table_A")

# Join
merged_df = table_df.join(df, on="Id", how="left")
```

### Option 2 - SQL way

The second option builds on your second bullet point:

> Tried to use spark.sql to perform the left join in a SQL query but it seems I cannot access a df inside a spark.sql query.

You can temporarily register DataFrame as a view, and then query it using plain SQL, whether in `spark.sql` method or any other way. Try doing this:

```py
df.createOrReplaceTempView("transformed_df")

# Then join like this
spark.sql("SELECT * FROM bronze.Table_A ta LEFT JOIN transformed_df tdf ON ta.Id = tdf.Id")
```

Comment: Thank you for providing two options, both worked out nicely.

Comment: No problem, glad to have helped :)